# Ionic2 Returning a value from Http request and assign it to variable

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to Ionic2 and I don't really understand how asynchronous programming works.

I want function `checkLogin()` to return the value of 0 or 1, however, instead it returns the result below. How do I make the variable `this.isLoggedIn`to be assigned the value I desire?

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Provider**

```
checkLogin() {
    var url = this.app.URL + 'api/program/information';
    var isLoggedIn;

    return this.http.get(url).map(res =>res.json()).subscribe( logininfo =>{
        if (!logininfo.data.information.is_logged_in) {
            isLoggedIn = 0;
        } else {
            isLoggedIn = 1;
        }
        return isLoggedIn;
    })
}
```

**home.ts**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.globalVar.checkLogin();
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
}
```

**result**
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return an observable from `checkLogin()` and subscribe to it in `home.ts`. Like this:

```
checkLogin() {
  var url = this.app.URL + 'api/program/information';
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

home.ts:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.globalVar.checkLogin()
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(logininfo => {
    if (!logininfo.data.information.is_logged_in) {
      this.isLoggedIn = 0;
    }
    else {
      this.isLoggedIn = 1;
    }
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
  },(err) => {
    console.log("Error occurred:",err);
  });
}
```

**NOTE**: All operations which are followed by this login information, will go in the `.subscribe()` of `this.globalVar.checkLogin()`. If you will try to access the `this.isLoggedIn` anywhere else than this, it might or might not be accessible. This is what an async operation is. You need to wait for it to get resolved. Other operations which are not dependent on this variable can carry forward outside of this function.

**UPDATE 1:** Shifting the `if()` part to a common method:

```
checkLogin() {
  var url = this.app.URL + 'api/program/information';
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(logininfo => {
      var isLoggedIn;

      if(!logininfo.data.information.is_logged_in) {
        isLoggedIn = 0;
      }
      else {
        isLoggedIn = 1;
      }

      observer.next(isLoggedIn);
    },(err) => {
      console.log("Error occurred:",err);
      observer.error(err);
    });
  });
}
```

home.ts:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.globalVar.checkLogin()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.isLoggedIn = data;
    console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
  },(err) => {
    console.log("Error occurred:",err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. The reason that I want to return simple value is that I have `checkLogin()` every tab, so I do not want to repeat subscribe part everytime. Is there any way I can return simple value such as 0 or 1?

Comment: Hey. For that I tried some things. At max you can shift your logic of `isLoggedIn` to the common `checkLogin()` method. But, `.subscribe()` will not have any alternative from a calling method Will update my answer for that.

Comment: Updated my answer. Also, since this is async, I think this is how you will have to wait for the event to get completed.

Answer (score 0):

You have subscribed in the provider. The `subscribe` function just returns a subscription and not the value. You should return the observable and subscribe in the component.

```
    checkLogin() {
    var url = this.app.URL + 'api/program/information';
    var isLoggedIn;

    return this.http.get(url).map(res =>{
        let logininfo = res.json();
        if (!logininfo.data.information.is_logged_in) {
            isLoggedIn = 0;
        } else {
            isLoggedIn = 1;
        }
        return isLoggedIn;
    })
}
```

In your component,

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.globalVar.checkLogin().subscribe(val=>{
       this.isLoggedIn=val;
       console.log(this.isLoggedIn);
   })
}
```

In order to use `do()` or any other `rxjs` functions, you need to explicitely import them.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

Comment: updated answer.. just import in provider `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';`

Comment: Thank you! it works. But `val` returns response result of http request instead of 0 or 1 which I expect.

Comment: oh ok.. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md it seems it is used mainly for logging.. will update answer..do it in `map` itself

Answer (score 0):

you can use promise function for asynchronous operation.

```
checkLogin() {
    var url = this.app.URL + 'api/program/information';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(url).map(res =>res.json()).subscribe( logininfo =>{
        if (!logininfo.data.information.is_logged_in) {
            resolve(0)
        } else {
            resolve(1)
        }
      },err=>{
        reject(err)
      })
    })
}
```

i hope its work for you.