# Ionic2: Making a get request in a service with HttpClient gets undefined on component

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I try to make a `GET` request using a service I can print successfully the response inside this service (`data.service.ts`) but when I try to get this on a component, it gets undefined (`send.component.ts`)

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map']

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    getBusiness(){
        this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1/business').subscribe(data => {
            this.BUSINESS = data;
            return this.BUSINESS;
        });
    }

    constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

}
```

**send.component.ts**

```
import { DataService } from '../../app/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-send',
  templateUrl: 'send.html'
})
export class SendPage {

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    this.title = navParams.get('title');

    console.log(dataService.getBusiness())
  }
}
```

**JSON response:**

```
[{
    "_id": "5a0cf90cf3de893b000b8e3b",
    "name": "business2",
    "boxes": ["dasdsadsdasbox", "dsadajhhgbox"],
    "users": ["user2"],
    "deleted": false
}, {
    "_id": "5a0cf90cf3de893b321321",
    "name": "business1",
    "boxes": ["dasds321321box", "ds321321hgbox"],
    "users": ["user1"],
    "deleted": false
}]
```

Why does it happens and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic2 Returning a value from Http request and assign it to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337354/ionic2-returning-a-value-from-http-request-and-assign-it-to-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code :

**data.service.ts**

```
getBusiness(){
       return new Promise(resolve => {
           this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1/business')
             .subscribe(data => {
               resolve(data.json());
             });
         });
}
```

**send.component.ts**

```
constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    this.title = navParams.get('title');
    dataService.getBusiness().then(res => {
       console.log('Responce =>'res);
    })
  }
```

Comment: it shows the error:

Typescript Error
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: now it gets the error: "res.json is not a function".. I updated my question with the json the request should return.

Comment: check i update it please  remove `.map(res => res.json())`

Comment: it fixed the problem. Tks! I would edit the answer to console.log('Response =>'+res) because it´s missing concatanation and response is mispelled

Comment: The new promise is not needed. getBusiness should return Observable and the component code should call subscribe.